# How do I dispose a form in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose

I had windows application which check if adobe acrobat installed in pc or not if it installed pdf file will display from cd if it is not installed installer window appear to setup the acrobat I did my code will but I want when pdf file run the windows form disposed I made that but this appeared:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Checker'.

```
public Checker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Check();                          
}
//static void main()
//{

//    Checker ck = new Checker();
//    ck.Show();
//    Application.Run();
//}
public  void Check()
{
    try
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("AMD");

        if (adobe == null)
        {
            panel1.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                switch (d.DriveType)
                {
                    case DriveType.CDRom:
                        Process myProcess = new Process();
                        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = d.Name + "Environment.docx";
                        myProcess.Start();

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error occured");
    }

    this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Can you not just close your form using Form.Close()?

Answer (score 2):

In the overwhelming majority of cases, you should *not* call `this.Dispose()` in your code. By placing this call in a method called from the constructor, you're essentially disposing the current object out from underneath yourself. The run-time detects that, and presents you with an error when you try to access your form object on the next line by calling its `Show` method.

In this case, if you want to close your form after the `Check` method finishes, you should just call its [`Close` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx):

```
this.Close();
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with calling dispose from your own object.  Form.Close calls it.  Granted, not in this situation, but I think generally speaking calling calling your own dispose method is not a terrible thing (just not common practice).

Comment: @Steve: That the internal implementation of a method calls `Dispose` on that same object is not a reason that doing so in your own code is good practice. In the case of a form, you should just call `this.Close()` instead. You're right, it's not going to blow up; I didn't say it would. I said that there's hardly *ever* a reason to do so.

Comment: any time you have unmanaged resources you need to make 100% sure your class gets disposed (where appropriate), and that typically means invoking your dispose method (if you follow best practices you dispose of those resources there)... Just saying, I don't think its a best practice not to call your own dispose (though whole heatedly agree that here it's not correct).  `Close` would be the correct place to do it on a Form

Comment: If you're using ShowDialog() instead of Show(), then Dispose() is encouraged by Microsoft. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8081989/848344

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing, is creating a form, disposing it, and **then** showing it.

Using explicit disposes is rarely good, but your problem is that you are trying to use the disposed object after it is disposed, so the application crashes.

Try to close the form in the `Check()` method, using `this.Close()`, and use the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to ensure that the form will indeed be disposed when you are done with it, like this:

```
using (Checker ck = new Checker())
{
    ck.Show();
}
Application.Run();
```

Comment: There's no reason that calling the `Dispose` method explicitly is bad. The only problem here is that the asker is calling `this.Dispose`. You should dispose *other* objects that implement `IDisposable` as soon as you're done using them.

Comment: @Cody - You should dispose (other) object when you are done with them, sure. I'm just saying that using `using` is usually the better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you call `this.Dispose();` in the `Check` method, which is called from the constructor. Essentially you are disposing the form in the contructor, making it impossible to use.

It seems to me as if you should separate the logic a bit here. Make a method that performs the check, returning a `bool` indicating whether the form should be displayed or not, and then create and display the form only if should show up on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are already disposing your form in the Check() method which is called in your constructor.

The show method is then executed, and at this stage, you object is already disposed.

Memory in .net is freed automatically, why do you want to call dispose explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Disposing the form is different from exiting the application.
Try Application.Exit().