# WinForms Dialog Form -- Close or Dispose?

Tags: winforms

I've inherited some code and wanted to run this modification by you all, my concern is memory management.

Let us say I have a "base" Form with a bunch of buttons that open "dialog" forms.  What is the recommended pattern for opening the dialog forms?  Currently we display the "dialog" form like so (in the "base" Form code, upon button click):

```
ChangePasswordForm frm = new ChangePasswordForm();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Then close it like so (in the "dialog" form code):

```
private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
  //this.Dispose();  <-- this is what I am considering adding.
}
```

My rationale for adding Dispose is that I am worried if this form is displayed and closed many times that each time a *new* instance of the form is created and its resources are never really released -- is this correct?  Also, if the form has the "close" X in the top right, should I put a Dispose() call in the FormClosed event as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I read this [link](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/09/what-difference-between-dispose-and.html) and found it interesting. Could help you, I hope.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would use a `using` statement:

```
  using (var frm = new ChangePasswordForm()) {
      frm.ShowDialog();
  }
```

Combine this with a DialogResult:

```
private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Setting the DialogResult, will close the Dialog, and the caller/owner has some feedback.

And you don't have to worry about Close or Dispose.

Comment: Thank you, is it the DialogResult being set that sends the using block "out of scope", so to speak?

Comment: Setting the DialogResult, will close the dialog, and the ShowDialog call will return. ShowDialog, shows the form in "modal" mode, the calling code is blocked until the dialog is closed.

Comment: Might be off topic, but if you set `DialogResult` in a form that was open using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`, will the form still close?

Comment: @ShooShoSha Setting the DialogResult will cause the special messageloop that is used for modal forms to stop running, this messageloop is not used for non-modal forms. Setting DialogResult on a non-modal form will not close the form.

Answer (score 21):

According to MSDN you need to dispose under two conditions:

> The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

[MSDN Form.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)

Declaring the form in a using statement would be the appropriate way to handle this.

```
        using (ChangePasswordForm frm = new ChangePasswordForm())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
```