# "Cannot access disposed object" error when launching a WinForm

Tags: .net, winforms, automation

I have a number of apps which examine the command line for parameters, launch a WinForm, and then if a flag was set run a process and close the form.  Thus I can run the process unsupervised.

I noticed that a couple of these apps were failing when run unsupervised, though they had the same structure as more than a dozen others, and ran fine when I ran them manually.

To recreate the problem:

```
static void Main()
    {
    bool  _unsupervised = ParseCommandLine();
    Application.Run(new FormUI(_unsupervised));
    }

class FormUI: Form
    {
    public FormUI(bool unsupervised)
        {
        _unsupervised = unsupervised;
        if (_unsupervised)  Start();
        }
    public void  Start()
        {
        // Do stuff
        if (_unsupervised)  Close();
        }
    private bool  _unsupervised;
    }
```

The result: `Application.Run()` throws `ObjectDisposedException`: "Cannot access a disposed object".

Similar: [How do I dispose a form in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076408/how-do-i-dispose-a-form-in-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these problem apps and the others was whether I put `Start()` (and therefore, the code path to `Close()`) in the constructor or the `Load()` method.  By doing the former, the form was creating and disposing itself before the app could launch it with `Application.Run()`.

The key is to move this action to some point after the constructor has completed, such as the `OnLoad` event.  This adjustment does the trick:

```
static void Main()
    {
    bool  _unsupervised = ParseCommandLine();
    Application.Run(new FormUI(_unsupervised));
    }

class FormUI: Form
    {
    public FormUI(bool unsupervised)
        {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormUI_Load);
        _unsupervised = unsupervised;
        }
    public void  Start()
        {
        // Do stuff
        if (_unsupervised)  Close();
        }
    private bool  _unsupervised;

    private void  FormUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        // Key change
        if (_unsupervised)  Start();
        }
    }
```

Now the `Start() .. Close()` path only occurs after the form has been fully created.